# What's the purpose of use_socket_read_watermark

Tags: network, plugin

How to use this parameter and why should we use it?

in config.ini there is a experimental parameter for

> socket read watermark optimization

`use-socket-read-watermark = 0`
in [net_plugin.cpp under plugin](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/3c6134c68fa4d52df58955bc1a1475f7adbf3cfa/plugins/net_plugin/net_plugin.cpp#L197)

`bool use_socket_read_watermark = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option appears to have been introduced in [v1.0.4](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/commit/474f88885783a1700203c61e37493fb971edafa0), and it enables [low-water marks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.14/gtpc1/gtpc1mst86.html) for socket communication to minimise the number of send calls required to get a minimum number of bytes (i.e. enable faster communication.) However, this is not widely supported; `poll(2)` in Linux [ignores SO_RCVLOWAT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), but OS X [may support it](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/4078#issuecomment-396966428).

Comment: so did it give any improvement in the performance ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any testing performed to answer this unfortunately